# Social icons/links on shopify Simple Theme won't show up

Tags: shopify

I'm tweaking the Simple theme and added social links on the customize page settings but I wonder why links won't show up. I didn't did anything in the `theme.liquid` to break the social links default template but why is it not showing. Can anyone guide me how to do it or explain to me why? Thanks in advance.

theme.liquid social template:

```
<ul class="list--inline social-links">
            {% if settings.social_facebook_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_facebook_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Facebook' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-facebook' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Facebook</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_twitter_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_twitter_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Twitter' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-twitter' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Twitter</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_pinterest_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_pinterest_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Pinterest' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-pinterest' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Pinterest</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_instagram_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_instagram_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Instagram' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-instagram' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Instagram</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_google_plus_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_google_plus_link }}" rel="publisher" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Google Plus' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-google-plus' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Google Plus</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_tumblr_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_tumblr_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Tumblr' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-tumblr' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Tumblr</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_youtube_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_youtube_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'YouTube' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-youtube' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">YouTube</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_vimeo_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_vimeo_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Vimeo' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-vimeo' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Vimeo</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.social_fancy_link != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="{{ settings.social_fancy_link }}" title="{{ 'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 'Fancy' }}">
                  {% include 'icon-fancy' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Fancy</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.show_atom and settings.main_blog != blank %}
              <li>
                <a href="/blogs/{{ settings.main_blog }}.atom">
                  {% include 'icon-rss' %}
                  <span class="icon__fallback-text">Blog</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
```

Comment: What is the Simple Theme you are referring to?

Comment: @jfox, It's called the Simple theme. I forgot the link. wait

Comment: I think they removed the theme. Can't find it now. this should be the link but it's now broken https://themes.shopify.com/themes/simple/styles/beauty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links will show up in the following cases:

1. You have set up the links in the `config/settings.json` or via the theme editor GUI.
2. The site is displayed in the relevant size - if the template is responsive it will hide the icons in order to have more space on the screen.

### **How to check if i have set up ithe links?**

Open the config file and check any value, for example: `settings.social_facebook_link`

```
Online Store > Themes > ... > Edit HTML/CSS
```

Open the config folder and you will see the `settings_data` file inside.
The flag to display it might need to be true as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I already added the links and it shows inside the settings_data.json but it won't appear on my theme. The theme also has social options but I wonder why it won't show.